# How to swich j and k when using Vim in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried this:

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["j"],
        "after": ["k"]
    },
    {
        "before": ["k"],
        "after": ["j"]
    }
]
```

After that j and k stops working completly. Is there any way to swap them?

Comment: Out of curiosity... why?

Comment: It feels more natural for me.

Comment: You probably need `vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive`, like `nnoremap` in standalone Vim.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same this but in:

```
"vim.visualModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["j"],
      "after": ["k"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["k"],
      "after": ["j"]
    }
  ]
```